# Properly target sources folder to return all file paths

Tags: node.js

Here is the real address of sources folder in my computer:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Server\views\app\files\sources
```

I have this middleware at the start of the server.js file in node.js:

```
app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + '/views/app/files'));
```

And inside `files` folder I have `sources` folder ok!!

Then I want to return all file addresses inside sources folder using this function:

```
function ThroughDirectory(Directory) {
        FS.readdirSync(Directory).forEach(File => {
            const Absolute = Path.join(Directory, File);
            if (FS.statSync(Absolute).isDirectory()) return ThroughDirectory(Absolute);
            else return Files.push(Absolute);
        });
}
console.log(ThroughDirectory("/app/sources"))
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/app/sources'
```

How can I properly address the sources folder?

Using this gives me undefined and error goes..

```
path.dirname(require.main.filename) + "/views/app/files/sources"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to look for `app/files/sources`, but `ThroughDirectory` function looks for `app/files/app/sources`.

Just remove 'app' from `Directory` path.

Code:

```
console.log(ThroughDirectory("/sources"))
```